# TFS Get all team specific iteration paths

Tags: tfs, tfs-2013

Need help with retrieving all team-specific iteration paths under a specific project. I used this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952536/how-to-get-all-iteration-paths-with-a-tfs-api-2013) to get some hint, but with `GetTeamConfigurationsForUser`, I get only such paths of the teams of which I belong to. Is there a way to get for all teams? Do `GetTeamConfigurations` work? For example, if I have a project ABC, under which there are 10 teams, I need to get all iteration paths when a specific team is selected (even though I'm not a member of that team as am able to see such in the TFS web mode). Following is the code snippet am currently using:

```cs
var project = css.GetProjectFromName(strProjectName);

var allteams = teamService.QueryTeams(strProjectName);
var iterations = new List<string>();

// to get all teams under a project
foreach (TeamFoundationTeam tfteam in allteams)
{
    areaList.Add(tfteam.Name);
}

var configs = teamConfig.GetTeamConfigurationsForUser(new[] { project.Uri.ToString() });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TeamSettingsConfigurationService.GetTeamConfigurationsForUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.processconfiguration.client.teamsettingsconfigurationservice.getteamconfigurationsforuser(v=vs.110).aspx)  method  get the team settings for teams that **the current user/identity is a member of** (scoped to a set of team projects)

You can try to use [TeamSettingsConfigurationService.GetTeamConfigurations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.processconfiguration.client.teamsettingsconfigurationservice.getteamconfigurations(v=vs.110).aspx) method which need team IDs

```
public IEnumerable<TeamConfiguration> GetTeamConfigurations(
    IEnumerable<Guid> teamIds
)
```

Comment: thank you. I was able to get the required results with GetTeamConfigurations method.

Comment: If it works, could you mark it as an answer. just click green √ on the left of the answer.